# Why is my hard drive still fragmented after I run defraggler?

Tags: hard-drive, defragment

I ran defraggler last night because and I let it run while I slept.  I woke up this morning and it still told me my hard drive was 20% fragmented.  So I ran it again before I left the house for a couple hours.  I come back, and it still says 19% fragmented.

What is the reason for this?  Is it normal or is there a problem with my hard drive?  I'm preparing to re-manage my partitions so I thought it would be smart to defrag first.

**Edit: After a third reanalysis, Puran Defrag and Defraggler both tell me I have only 125mb fragmentation.  Just some kind of fluke I guess.**

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to use a [better defragger](http://www.puransoftware.com/) that can do boot time defrag.

Comment: I agree... some defraggers cough cough "windows" cough cough, aren't as robust or as good.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you've not enough free space in each partition. And make sure to run Defraggler before the OS start if it's able to.

Comment: I am not aware of Defraggler having the capability to run off a live cd.  And I do not understand what you mean by, "Maybe you've not enough free space in each partition."

Comment: When Defraggler tries to defragment your partitions he does a kind of *housekeeping* so it needs to move your data within your partition to create the largest possible contiguous empty space. So it needs some room to make these operations: more room means more chances to success. You may want to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

Certain files such as those currently in use and certain operating system files can't be moved (or not, at least, while the system is running). A couple of examples might include device drivers and the swap file (if present). I'm fairly comfortable saying that you'll *probably* never get the fragmentation percentage down to 0.

Comment: Do you know of a defragging program that will run outside of windows?  Like on a live cd?

Comment: Very, very strange.  I just re-analyzed my hard drive with Puran Defrag like CGA suggested, and it told me I have only 125 mb fragmentation!  I then went back into defraggler and it also said the same thing.  I don't understand it, but oh well.  I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 1):

I do a defragmentation using Diskeeper on the 1st of every month, and this time my hard drive wasn't too fragmented but it was kind of fragmented so I ran the defrag and then after it was done it was still a little bit fragmented...when I used to do this..it would get 100% defragmented. I think it happens when it gets TOO fragmented!

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the restore files. Turn off system restore ( have an image available just in case)
Run defraggl;er and turn restore back on

Answer (score 0):

The MFT cannot be defragmented while the volume is in use.  Neither can files that represent some registry files, the pagefile, `C:\hiberfil.sys`.

You need a defragmentation program that can run before Windows starts (like `chkdsk` does) to do that.